# Minitoc top align

Tags: minitoc

When I apply `minitoc` and the table of contents spill over to the next page, it automatically fills the entire page instead of being aligned to the top.

[image: correct alignment]

[image: wrong alignment]

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{book} 


\usepackage{minitoc} % for mini content page 
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2} 
\dominitoc[n] % for mini content page

\begin{document}

\faketableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\minitoc  

\pagebreak[4]

\section{Section 1}
This is section 1.
\subsection{Subsection 1}
This is subsection 1.
\subsection{Subsection 2}
This is subsection 2.
\subsection{Subsection 3}
This is subsection 3. 

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}

\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}

\section{Section 4}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}

\section{Section 5}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}

\section{Section 6}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You requested this behaviour with

```
\pagebreak[4]
```

use

```
\clearpage
```

If you want to leave the page short. You see the same with linebreaking and the difference between `\linebreak` and `\newline`.

Comment: Perfect! I have always been using pagebreak[4] to force a new page, not knowing that clearpage works wonderfully!